# Alternative to "consumer" that encapsulates viewer/reader/listener/etc

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for a word that refers to one who *x*es a piece of media or describes the action of *x*ing a piece of media, where *x* is the act by which one experiences that work, and where "piece of media" means an informative (i.e. characterized by its provision or conveyance of information, but not necessarily edifying or educational) work. Viewer/viewing works for film and television, reader/reading for prose and poetry, listener/listening for music and spoken word, but none are agnostic to the type of its respective medium.

I'm specifically avoiding *consumer*, *partaker*, and *user* due to the implication that the work is destroyed when one *x*es it.

I'm not averse to simply writing reader/viewer/listener, but if a briefer alternative exists I would be glad to learn of it.

Comment: I would suggest _target_ or _victim_, if we're generalizing to actual media.

Comment: @JohnLawler *Target* seems to imply plurality, as in *target audience* or *target demographic*, whereas *viewer* or *reader* refers to a single entity. I'm not sure how *victim* could fit this context.

Comment: *Perceive* has just occurred to me as a generic alternative to listen/view/read, although it fails in the case of an interactive medium.

Comment: Get a thesaurus, I suggest Roget's but there are many others available now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *participant*: one who participates in an activity.

A *subject*. Perhaps it's a little off the beaten path, but a subject subjects himself or herself to an informative medium. They then become informed, and the information informs them (i.e., changes or affects them in some way).

What you describe is a form of *interaction* or *interacting*. There is not yet a word, however, for an interactor, except when the word applies to the *InterActor* which is the medium of web conferencing. Look [here](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/_/viewer.aspx?path=9%2F9d%2F&name=Lee_Odden_on_Twebinar.jpg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fencyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com%2FWeb%2Bconferencing) and [here](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/Web+conferencing) for possible ideas.

By the way, *auditor* is a perfectly good word, although its primary application is to the hearing process at work in a speaker-to-audience event or relationship (or more technically, rhetor-to-auditor event or relationship).

Even "further out there" is a *dyadic event*, in which two people are communicating electronically (assuming there is an interactive component to the communication). A telephone/cellphone/smartphone conversation is a relatively simple medium of informative communication. One person sends information while the other person receives; then the roles are reversed in a sort of ongoing feedback loop.

Not knowing the media to which you refer, I'm at a loss to know what kind of interface there is between the informant and the person being informed. In our electronic age, the possibilities are virtually endless, not to mention mind boggling, especially for Boomers like me.

Finally, there's the good old *dialogue* which, again, in our electronic age is no longer simply a face-to-face interaction in which people are dialoguing with each in person without the aid of any electronic medium whatsoever (unless you consider to be electronic the electrical activity of synapses firing in the bodies of the people who are dialoguing).

In conclusion, perhaps you could give us more information about the media of which you are speaking and how they/it function(s).

Answer (score 4):

Every creative work has an ***[audience](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/audience)***:

> 1. The assembled spectators or listeners at a public event such as a play, film, concert, or meeting:
>      1.1 The people who watch or listen to a television or radio programme:
>      1.2 The readership of a newspaper, magazine, or book
>      1.3 The people giving attention to something

[ODO]

In advertising and public relations, *audience* usually refers to a *[target audience](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/target-audience.html)*, people specifically intended to receive the message of a campaign, and is to be distinguished from the concept of a *public*, classically defined as a self-organizing group of interested persons.

There is no common verb form for being a member of an audience, however.

Comment: "There is no common verb form for being a member of an audience, however."  *Auditor/auditing*, perhaps? It refers to a hearer or listener, but it's possible common use of "audience" in the context you describe would lend it the same connotation.

Comment: @Slade Fair enough, but I think this use of *audit* and *auditor* is much less common than the more active sense of inspecting or assessing is. Students auditing a class would probably not refer to themselves as *auditors*.

Answer (score 1):

"User"? "recipient"? "receiver"? I know exactly what you mean - there seems to be no commonly used word for what you describe, but one wishes there was. I'm cheered to find that someone else feels that "to consume information" (or art, or books, etc.) is a bit revolting.