# A generic term for both books and movies?

Tags: books, generic-term

I need to know this for an essay I'm doing. I thinks media might work but I'm not really sure. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Media would generally be associated with film and news mediums rather than literary texts.

Comment: @WindowsDude7 True, but that's mainly when talking about "the media" rather than "media". Plenty of artists talk about employing "mixed media". I don't think anyone would think you just meant Fox and CNN if you talked about "expressing your views through a variety of media", for example.

Comment: @ParthianShot - You are quite correct. I actually had newspapers in mind. They are an interesting text medium because they can undoubtedly be referred to as "media".

Comment: Related, though not duplicates: *[Hypernym for “movie” and “TV series”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127196)*, *[Alternative to “consumer” that encapsulates viewer/reader/listener/etc](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225139)*

Comment: story holders - may I ask why you want to know this?

Answer (score 6):

Try *works*. I don't think there's a term that covers specifically books and movies other than just naming them as what they are.

Comment: And also *work of art*, which can describe a lot of things.

Answer (score 1):

**Pieces**

A piece of art, a play piece, a piece as in script, a piece as in book, and a movie (piece).

Comment: Hello and welcome to ELU! Could you please provide a definition or citation for this answer?

Answer (score 0):

fiction is a good word to use for describing both books and movies

Comment: "Fiction" only includes stories that describe imaginary events. Many books and movies wouldn't fall under the classification of fiction.

Answer (score -3):

> Brain candy

Might be a fairly slang, even sarcastic, way of describing such entertainment materials.